# using libpath in python to map a file from one OS to another and slashes are wrong

Tags: python, path

I have a python script that works with another program via API. I need to send the program the directory of a file. The problem I am having is I need to account for the possible difference in paths if the script and program are on different machines and/or OSes. If the script and program are on the same machine it's not an issue. But if they are on different machines, the machine with the script will have a networked path:

script (mapped network drive):
`Z:\files\file.txt`

program:
`/mnt/user/disk1/files/file.txt`

So the Z drive points to the mapped networked drive the program has access to.

```
import pathlib

location = 'Z:\\files\\file.txt'
map_source = 'Z:\\'
map_destination = '/mnt/user/disk1/'
newpath=(location.replace(map_source, ''))
print(pathlib.PurePath(map_destination, newpath))
```

So if I give the script `Z:\files\file.txt` as input, it should remove `Z:\` from `location` and replace it with `/mnt/user/disk1/` and return `/mnt/user/disk1/files/file.txt`. The problem is it is returning with the wrong slashes:

```
\mnt\user\disk1\files\file.txt
```

How can I get it to determine what the correct slashes should be? My understanding is `PurePath` will do the correct slash depending on the OS the script is run but I might be running this on a Windows machine and sending the path to a Linux machine. I realize I can probably do this manually with a regex or something but is there some way with `libpath` or some already existing module? I can't just tell it what to convert it I don't know what system the destination will be. I suppose it would have to parse it and figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

> I realize I can probably do this manually with a regex or something but is there some way with libpath or some already existing module?

Use the specific PurePath subclasses? PurePath dispatches between `pathlib.PurePosixPath` and `pathlib.PureWindowsPath` internally based on the system it's being run on, but you can use these subclasses directly if you know what's what.

Not that it'll help much, as I don't think there's any real "bridge" between the two: PurePath (and its subclasses) can take path segments as input, but doesn't return path segments.

Also note that your windows paths are broken, `\` is an escape character in non-raw python strings so e.g. `\f` is going to be interpreted as [ASCII Formfeed (FF)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_break#Form_feed).

Comment: The problem is I can't know what the destination system will be. It could be on Windows or Linux. I was hoping it would realize it from the path. The broken path from the slash was just a copy/paste error. I have it escaped properly in my code.

Comment: You could try to guess but you'll have to handroll it. And technically paths with forward slashes are often valid Windows paths.

Comment: Yes, but they aren't with Linux. I need to cover ever use case. I decided the only thing to do for now is to include a config setting for the user to specify the destination system.

Comment: It's the backslashes which aren't valid unix paths.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.